# How can I construct an email address from a cell containing firstname lastname?

Tags: excel, string, email

I wish to either automatically add code as I create an Excel macro, or if necessary manually insert the code into an existing macro: Construct email addresses in a column, from another column whose cells contain firstname lastname.  Example: John Smith in column A becomes JSmith@aol.com in column B.  The mailbox name is always the same, of course.  The code will process all the rows in the column.

Comment: This could be done with a formula. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
=left(A1,1)&mid(A1,find(" ",A1,1)+1,20)&"@aol.com"
```

I have just checked the order of the arguments in mid() and it works.

Note if there are double barreled names then you have to consider that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try in this way as well, if there is only **FIRST NAME** & **LAST NAME**,

• Formula used in cell **B2**

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(A2),REPLACE(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2),""),"@aol.com")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Answer (score 0):

Before I received these solutions, I first used Data > Text to Columns to split the name; then I used the following successfully (I substituted "[domain]" for security purposes): =LOWER(LEFT(J1)&K1&"@"&"[domain].com")

I may try these solutions so as to save the Data step.  Note: I believe all our logins are only two names.